# How to make a fixed-size byte variable in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, byte

Let's say, I have a string (Unicode if it matters) variable which is less than 100 bytes. I want to create another variable with exactly 100 byte in size which includes this string and is padded with zero or whatever. How would I do it in Python 3?

Comment: Is this for displaying the string, or for some other reason?

Comment: @CodyPiersall, I need to send fixed-size byte over network so I can assemble the packet on the other side.

Comment: the byte-size of a string depends on the encoding... Are you talking about strings in the sense of 'text' or strings in the sense of data b'\x00' ?

Comment: @ChrisWesseling, the latter suits me better I think.

Comment: @Daenyth, 3 my friend.

Comment: When you say "padded with zero" do you mean the character `0` or a null byte?

Comment: @MarkRansom, doesn't really matter but I think null byte can be discarded easier later on.

Comment: If you don't know what it is padded with, how can you distinguish the padding from the actual data on the receiving end?

Comment: @MikaelS. Well it really *does* matter... If you pad your strings with b'\x90', than some viruscheckers and firewalls may take them for a [NOP-slide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_slide) and put your bytes in quarantaine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For assembling packets to go over the network, or for assembling byte-perfect binary files, I suggest using the `struct` module.

- [struct — Interpret bytes as packed binary data](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/struct.html)

Just for the string, you might not need `struct`, but as soon as you start also packing binary values, `struct` will make your life much easier.

Depending on your needs, you might be better off with an off-the-shelf network serialization library, such as Protocol Buffers; or you might even just use JSON for the wire format.

- [Protocol Buffer Basics: Python](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial)
- [PyMOTW - JavaScript Object Notation Serializer](http://pymotw.com/2/json/)

Comment: Although this is not directly an answer to my question but that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this should work:

```
st = "具有"
by = bytes(st, "utf-8")
by += b"0" * (100 - len(by))
print(by)
# b'\xe5\x85\xb7\xe6\x9c\x890000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

Obligatory addendum since your original post seems to conflate strings with the length of their encoded byte representation: [Python unicode explanation](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)

Answer (score 3):

To pad with null bytes you can do it the way they do it in the stdlib [base64](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/4fc571a04c9c/Lib/base64.py#l160) module.

```
some_data = b'foosdsfkl\x05'
null_padded = some_data + bytes(100 - len(some_data))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a roundabout way of doing it:

```
>>> import sys
>>> a = "a"
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
22
>>> a = "aa"
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
23
>>> a = "aaa"
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
24
```

So following this, an **ASCII** string of 100 bytes will need to be 79 characters long

```
>>> a = "".join(["a" for i in range(79)])
>>> len(a)
79
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
100
```

This approach above is a fairly simple way of "calibrating" strings to figure out their lengths.  You could automate a script to pad a string out to the appropriate memory size to account for other encodings.

```
def padder(strng):
    TARGETSIZE = 100
    padChar = "0"

    curSize = sys.getsizeof(strng)

    if curSize <= TARGETSIZE:
        for i in range(TARGETSIZE - curSize):
            strng = padChar + strng

        return strng
    else:
        return strng  # Not sure if you need to handle strings that start longer than your target, but you can do that here
```

Comment: Thanks but the size of `a = "具有"` is 42.

Comment: Doesn't `sys.getsizeof` try to show the size of some object in the vm's memory? That varies from platform to platform and implementation to implementation. On my machine it varies from `43` in python2.7, to `78` in python3.3 to `TypeError: sys.getsizeof() not implemented on PyPy`. I doubt this is what @MikaelS. was after...

Comment: @ChrisWesseling: Yeah. As if it's not bad enough that the answer's own text starts with "Here's a roundabout way of doing it", that way turns out to be completely wrong anyway.